# App got stuck when switching the UISwith on Xcode 11 and iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, touch-event, uiswitch, xcode11

I have Updated my Xcode from version 10 to 11.

But now my App is not accepting any touch events or it is getting stuck while I turn the `UISwitch`. 
Then I removed all the connections from the `UISwitch` to check whether the mistake is from my code. But Still I am getting the same issue.

Does anybody have an idea to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this possible to attach the project,

Comment: Yes It can. But whenever I changes the switch position the app will get stuck. And the I tried with a new switch without giving an outlet, that time also the same issue occur.

Comment: @[Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8399124/gregory-wilson-pullyattu) - I understand its some UI hierarchy mistake

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Is there any solution for that

Comment: with out see the code or UI, how can we say the issue ,

Comment: Actually there is no outlet or action for the switch. so there is no code for that. I  just drag and drop the switch into storyboard.

Comment: I also did the same , its works fine for me , plz add some video or else , its easy to understand the scenario.

Comment: I have the same issue with somebody running my app on iOS 13. The same app with the UISwitch does still work on my test devices and my Iphone all running iOS 12 or lower. 
I haven't upgrades to Xcode 11 yet, since I always wait for at least an .2 version, so I didn't had the change to actually debug this in iOS 13

Comment: Aren't you doing something in `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` func?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I had the exact same problem on devices running iOS 13, and when I started running Xcode 11. The problem (for me at least) was that Apple (probably) made a bug fix for the issue with the "valueChanged" hook to a UISwitch, see:

- [iOS7 UISwitch its Event ValueChanged: Calling continuously is this Bug or what..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628310/ios7-uiswitch-its-event-valuechanged-calling-continuously-is-this-bug-or-what)
- [Setting UISwitch isOn programmatically from IBAction calls IBAction again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589407/setting-uiswitch-ison-programmatically-from-ibaction-calls-ibaction-again)

Either way, what happened before was that the action for the switch got triggered twice, so I (apparently) set the switch to the right state myself. Like this:

```
@IBAction func notificationsSwitchTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn{
        sender.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }else{
        sender.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

But as of iOS 13 Xcode 11, the "valueChanged" UISwitch bug got fixed and the .isOn() value I am checking, actually already is the new value:

```
@IBAction func notificationsSwitchTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn{
        // The switch has been turned on
    }else{
        // The switch has been turned off
    }
}
```

Long story short, your switch probably got called twice before so your Boolean of the UISwitch's state is the opposite for your Xcode 11 iOS 13 code.